# Who won in this scenario? Both players have a pair

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, hand-reading

Me and a couple friends were playing poker and me and one of my friends had a pair. She had a pair in her hands and I had a pair using one of the cards from the flop. She had a Pair Of Q's, I had a pair of A's. I used an Ace From the table to make my pair and her pair is in her hand, who won?

Comment: You haven't actually given us enough information to answer the question unless we make some assumptions. Next time you ask, tell us what all 9 cards are (your two, his two, the five on the board).

Comment: Your pair wins, regardless if it's paired with the board, even if your friend have a pocket-pair like `QQ` or `KK` eg. using both her cards. This doesn't give value since the combination of five 5-card matters, now how much of your hole cards are you using.

Comment: You can't find the answer to this with a simple google search?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are playing Texas Hold'em. Its the best 5 card hand using ANY combination of your hole cards (Cards in your hand) and the community cards (cards on the table).

You won the hand with a pair of Aces. Pair of Aces > Pair of Queens.